# How to iterate through dynamic JSON keys using scala?

Tags: json, scala

I am beginner to scala.

I have a list that contains following data:

```
"Commands" : {
"system1" : "Name-ABC;IP-null; CPU-16;Mem-4096;id-1",
"system2" : "Name-XYZ;IP-null;CPU-4;Mem-2048;id-2",
"system3" : "Name-PQR;IP-null;CPU-2;Mem-2048;id-3",
"system4" : "Name-LMN;IP-192.168.20.22;CPU-2;Mem-1600;id-4"
"someotherkey":"some other value"
}
```

In above json, keys system1,2,3... are dynamic keys. I don't know exact number of keys (system) also.
After iterating I want to split value by ';' and then by '-' in order to access value of key.

e.g. I want to access 'Name'='ABC' from above json

How do I iterate through json with dynamic keys using scala?
Is it possible to use map?

Comment: Do you have access to the software that creates the JSON? If you do, your problem here is that you should treat the systems as an array, otherwise you could binary search for which key that actually exists, so start with 0 - 1000, and then in log(1000) you will know how many keys you actually have.

Comment: Don't have access. so cant modify JSON.

Comment: Ah ok, well then I guess the smartest thing to do would be to just check if a flag is present, starting with `system1` and if present read it else your done with the system tags?